# How to define a table alias before query in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I would like to use short name of a table in mysql query.
It it possible to define it before the `select`?

I'm looking for something similar:

```
SET mt = my_table; 
SELECT * FROM mt;
```

instead of:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table mt;
```

Comment: why will you want to define the table alias name before you use it?

Comment: in stored procedures you can build a string and the execute it and do something similiar. Else it is **impossible**

Comment: @D-Shih in order to make the main query shorter

Comment: You *probably* need Views ? Refer: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/views.html